# Java Cache and Hash Maps

Tags: java, caching, hashmap, hashtable

I am a complete newbie to Java programming and I am trying to learn caching and hash tables. I have seen tutorials online but they are complex, does anyone here know of any relatively short programs that utilise caching and hash tables?

Thanks for any help given

UPDATE:

I am basically starting from scratch. I know hash tables and sort of know caching (more simple caching programs would be much appreciated), but I don't get how the two work together. For example saving to a hash table and caching the data.

Comment: You're expected to show some research or an attempt. You haven't put enough effort into this question. Please specify exactly what you don't understand

Comment: Caching is just storing the result of an action so you dont need to perform that action again. Hash maps are just a data structure you use to store some data in. Just research how to use a hashmap and put some data in it and retrieve it later (a cache).

Comment: I dont get how to place data in the hash map and then retrieve it using a cache

Comment: Can you explain if you know anything about them in another language, or just the theory behind them?  Sounds like no?

Comment: Just the theory. I am basically starting from scratch. I know hash tables and sort of know caching, but I don't get how the two work together. For example saving to a hash table and caching the data

Answer (score 1):

As the comments mention, a cache is just a store where you keep the output so you won't have to do the calculation again.

Here's a really simple example

```
Map<String,Double> answers = new HashMap<String,Double>();

// checking cache if we have the answer

If (answers.get("volatility") != null) {
     System.out.println("volatility found in cache:" + 
   answers.get("volatility"));
}

// store a value in cache

answers.put("rate",1.887);
```

Comment: Thank you that is working and has helped me a lot. Is this using cache? for example can another class use this?